# Cannot implicitly convert from type 'void' to 'bool'

Tags: c#

I hope that I am not asking a rather stupid question now. I have searched quite some time on Google, but I can't seem to find the answer -- or maybe I just lack the understanding of how it works.

I hope that someone can explain to me why this error occurs? I keep getting the error: "Cannot implicitly convert from type 'void' to 'bool'".

This is the code:

```
class User
{
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _FirstName; }
        set
        {
                 // the error occurs on the line below
            if((ArgChecker.ThrowOnStringNullOrWhiteSpace(_FirstName) ) )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("something1");
            }
            else { _FirstName = value; }
        }
    }
    private string _FirstName;
}


class ArgChecker
{
    public static void ThrowOnStringNullOrWhiteSpace(string arg)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arg))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("something2");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for `if` Just invoke `ArgChecker.ThrowOnStringNullOrWhiteSpace(_FirstName)`

Comment: See the [void](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah0tteb.aspx) language reference. `void` is what you are returning from your method. An `if` statement should always check a `boolean` (true/false). `void` cannot be implicitly or explicitly converted to a `boolean`, hence the error.

Comment: Thank you for clearing out what casued the error. I appreciate it!

Comment: It would be cleaner to return a bool in most cases

Comment: @BrianWhite would you care to perhaps make an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can not convert void to bool, Instead your property should be something like

```
public string FirstName
{
    get { return _FirstName; }
    set
    {
        ArgChecker.ThrowOnStringNullOrWhiteSpace(value);
        _FirstName = value; 
    }
}
```

Comment: `ArgChecker.ThrowOnStringNullOrWhiteSpace(_FirstName);` should be `ArgChecker.ThrowOnStringNullOrWhiteSpace(value);`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be passing **value** into your ThrowOnStringNullOrWhiteSpace function (instead of _FirstName)?

Comment: I really should, yes. Stupid mistake. Thank you!